# How can I read a ".da" file directly into R?

Tags: r

I want to work with the [Health and Retirement Study](http://hrsonline.isr.umich.edu/) in R. Their website provides ".da" files and a SAS extract program. The SAS program reads the ".da" files like a fixed width file:

```
libname EXTRACT 'c:\hrs1994\sas\' ; 

DATA EXTRACT.W2H;
INFILE 'c:\hrs1994\data\W2H.DA'  LRECL=358; 

INPUT 
  HHID $ 1-6
  PN $ 7-9
  CSUBHH $ 10-10
  ETC ETC    
;

LABEL
  HHID ="HOUSEHOLD IDENTIFIER"
  PN ="PERSON NUMBER"
  CSUBHH ="1994 SUB-HOUSEHOLD IDENTIFIER"
  ASUBHH ="1992 SUB-HOUSEHOLD IDENTIFIER"
  ETC ETC
;
```

1) What type of file is this? I can't find anything about this file type.

2) Is there an easy way to read this into R without the intermediate step of exporting a .csv from SAS? Is there a way for `read.fwf()` to work without explicitly stating hundreds of variable names?

Thank you!

Comment: I just created an account with the Health and Retirement Study website and tried parsing some of their files with no luck. Do you have access to SPSS or STATA or SAS? You could use one of those platforms and export in the native format for the R package `foreign` to read.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and efforts. The goal is to read the file directly, not to use SPSS, STATA, or SAS. Is this possible and practical?

Comment: A quick google search yielded references to the R function `read.fwf`.  Did you try using that?

Comment: If they don't publish the metadata for the data files in a machine readable table then you could just parse the values from the SAS program. A command to read HHID from column 1 to column 6 means that HHID uses 6 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little more research it appears that you can utilize the Stata dictionary files *.DCT to retrieve the formatting for the data files *.DA. For this to work you will need to download both the "Data files" .zip file, and the "Stata data descriptors" .zip file from the HRS website. Just remember when processing the files to use the correct dictionary file on each data file. IE, use the "W2FA.DCT" file to define "W2FA.DA".

```
library(readr)

# Set path to the data file "*.DA"
data.file <- "C:/h94da/W2FA.DA"

# Set path to the dictionary file "*.DCT"
dict.file <- "C:/h94sta/W2FA.DCT"

# Read the dictionary file
df.dict <- read.table(dict.file, skip = 1, fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Set column names for dictionary dataframe
colnames(df.dict) <- c("col.num","col.type","col.name","col.width","col.lbl")

# Remove last row which only contains a closing }
df.dict <- df.dict[-nrow(df.dict),]

# Extract numeric value from column width field
df.dict$col.width <- as.integer(sapply(df.dict$col.width, gsub, pattern = "[^0-9\\.]", replacement = ""))

# Convert column types to format to be used with read_fwf function
df.dict$col.type <- sapply(df.dict$col.type, function(x) ifelse(x %in% c("int","byte","long"), "i", ifelse(x == "float", "n", ifelse(x == "double", "d", "c"))))

# Read the data file into a dataframe
df <- read_fwf(file = data.file, fwf_widths(widths = df.dict$col.width, col_names = df.dict$col.name), col_types = paste(df.dict$col.type, collapse = ""))

# Add column labels to headers
attributes(df)$variable.labels <- df.dict$col.lbl
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but that doesn't work. `read_fwf(INFILE, fwf_empty(INFILE), guess_max = 100000)` results in 11,596 rows and one column of random numbers. I guess I will need to specifcy the widths? Do you know the filetype?

Comment: You need to tell `read.fwf` how wide each field is. That information should be easy to see in any SAS, SPSS or STATA program that they have published to read the data.

Comment: My latest update will allow you to read the fixed width file using the data dictionary from the Stata .DCT file. For more information on what the data actually means, the Codebook zip file provides .txt files with information on the data, and the Questionnaire  zip file provides the actually questions which were asked when obtaining the data.

Comment: @MattJewett Wow, this works perfectly. Thank you for the help!

Do you know what a *.da file is?

Comment: I don't know if *.DA has a particular definition. In this case it seems to just represent the fact that it is a data file. Since the structure of the file is simply that of a fixed width file. You could just as easily give the file a .txt extension instead and achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for this post!   I just used it to extract the HRS2020 data.

Update for HRS2020 - also need to remove row 1 after removing the last row

```
# Remove first row
df.dict <- df.dict[-1,]
```